# Spring log multipart data responses and post request

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, servlets

I am trying to log requests and responses using a custom logger class. It was all working perfectly until I started getting Http requests with 'multipart/data' types.

Since then all 'multipart/data' types sent are throwing errors and not functioning properly.

I first got an error saying: Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided

So I tried to grab those specific multipart responses and manage them differently but to no avail. I removed the super.doDispatcher(req, res) I am not sure this is the right way to go.

Here is my loggger class:

```
public class LoggableDispatcherServlet extends DispatcherServlet {

    private final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    @Override
    protected void doDispatch(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        if (!(request instanceof ContentCachingRequestWrapper)) {
            request = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request);
        }
        if (!(response instanceof ContentCachingResponseWrapper)) {
            response = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);
        }
        HandlerExecutionChain handler = getHandler(request);

        boolean mulipart = false;
        try {
            if (request.getContentType() != null && request.getContentType().toLowerCase().contains("multipart/form-data")){
                logger.info("MULTIPART FILE RECEIVED");
                mulipart = true;
            }else
                super.doDispatch(request, response);

        }catch(Exception e){
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }finally {
            if (mulipart){
                response = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);                
                log(request, null, handler);               
                updateResponse(response);
            } else {
                log(request, response, handler);
                updateResponse(response);
            }
        }
    }

    private void log(HttpServletRequest requestToCache, HttpServletResponse responseToCache, HandlerExecutionChain handler) {
        LogMessage log = new LogMessage();
        log.setHttpMethod(requestToCache.getMethod());
        log.setUrl(requestToCache.getRequestURI());
        log.setClientIp(requestToCache.getRemoteAddr());
        log.setJavaMethod(handler.toString());
        if(responseToCache != null){
            log.setHttpStatus(responseToCache.getStatus());
            log.setResponse(getResponsePayload(responseToCache));
        }
        logger.info(log);
    }

    private String getResponsePayload(HttpServletResponse response) {
        ContentCachingResponseWrapper wrapper = WebUtils.getNativeResponse(response, ContentCachingResponseWrapper.class);
        if (wrapper != null) {

            byte[] buf = wrapper.getContentAsByteArray();

            if (buf.length > 0) {
                int length = Math.min(buf.length, 5120);
                try {
                    return new String(buf, 0, length, wrapper.getCharacterEncoding());
                }
                catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
                }
            }
        }
        return "[unknown]";
    }


    private void updateResponse(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        ContentCachingResponseWrapper responseWrapper =
                WebUtils.getNativeResponse(response, ContentCachingResponseWrapper.class);
        responseWrapper.copyBodyToResponse();
    }

}
```

It fails in the updateResponse(response) part when multipart = true. I tried to send different responses, I would live with sending even empty response but it just not processing it correctly and the class is not proceeding to the controller when this is multipart.

UPDATE:

If I remove the logger class then the request goes straight to the controller and it works perfectly.

This is how the Beans are initialized:

```
import com.altair.autoTester.logs.LoggableDispatcherServlet;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

@Configuration
public class LogsConfig {

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherRegistration() {
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(dispatcherServlet());
    }

    @Bean(name = DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DEFAULT_DISPATCHER_SERVLET_BEAN_NAME)
    public DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet() {
        return new LoggableDispatcherServlet();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an `else` that should probably not be there.

```
           if (request.getContentType() != null && request.getContentType().toLowerCase().contains("multipart/form-data")){
                logger.info("MULTIPART FILE RECEIVED");
                mulipart = true;
            }else
                super.doDispatch(request, response);
```

should be

```
           if (request.getContentType() != null && request.getContentType().toLowerCase().contains("multipart/form-data")){
                logger.info("MULTIPART FILE RECEIVED");
                mulipart = true;
            }
            super.doDispatch(request, response);
```

Comment: When I execute 'super.doDispatch(request, response)' with the multipart content I get the error listed above: "Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided"

Comment: Does your code work when the logging servlet is removed?

Comment: Yes, it works. It goes straight to the controller and execute the functions normally, with the ServletDispatcher it doesn't even get to the controller

Comment: Just to be sure, this is `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet` we are talking about, right? Is it created inside of the Spring context (aka @Bean)?

Comment: correct, this is the class I am using and it is initialized with the @Bean annotation. I updated the answer with the initializing class

Comment: I think the issue here is that the "default" dispatcher initializes its resolver somehow and it is not done here. You might want to call initStrategies on the parent I think: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/ce94f69e525282b418f801e9d734070ad5cbfc45/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.java#L496